# How to generate exponentially distributed time period in a stateless manner

Tags: simulation, exponential-distribution

I am doing an objected based computer simulation, with some of the objects having a lifetime that persist for an exponentially distributed time. One way to do this is

```
initialize object
  T_end = - log(rand) / lambda
  T = 0
end

on each iteration
  T = T + dt
  exit if T >= T_end
end
```

I would like to do this in a stateless manner i.e

```
on each interation
  exit if f(lambda, rand, dt) > threshold
end
```

where f is function of lambda, rand, and dt such that the objects have an exponentially distributed lifetime with paramater lambda. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the scenario you've described, the number of objects remaining $N$ varies with time as,

$$N = N_0 \exp(-\lambda t)$$

where $N_0$ is the value of $N$ at time $t = 0$. This is the solution to the ordinary differential equation,

$$\frac{\partial N}{\partial t} = -\lambda N$$

You might recognize this as a simple "rate equation" you learned in a chemistry class. Using the Euler method of integration, which is accurate for small enough steps in time, we get,

$$\Delta N/N = - \lambda \Delta t$$

So,

$$P(\text{exit}) = \lambda \Delta t$$

At each time step, you can generate a uniform random number between 0 and 1 and exit the particle if the random number is less than $\lambda \Delta t$. Make sure you use a small enough time step, or else a more sophisticated integration scheme.